# How to programmatically clone/create AWS EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have the need to get a prepared/configured AWS EC2 instance (my template instance), clone it (into the same region) get the corresponding IP address of the newly created instance, change its hostname and run a script inside of it to start a Node.js program using PM2.

I saw the CLI approach as well as the SDK for Node.js (because the creator program is a Nose.js endpoint), but I wasn't able to figure out how to accomplish this use case. It seems CLI has some limitations about configuring it, and the SDK in creating it, it only configures.

Does AWS exposes an integrated and official process for cloning (or at least creating), returning it's IP addr,starting, configuring and running a script inside of it?

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two approaches.

**No configuration**

If you have a script to fully install all the required software, then you could simply:

- Launch a new instance using a standard AMI
- Provide a User Data script that will execute the first time the instance is started. This script should install and start all desired software and apps.

When an Amazon EC2 instance is launched, information is returned about the new instance, including the `PrivateIpAddress`.

**Pre-Configured**

If you have a complex configuration on the instance, or you're not sure how the instance has been created, you could:

- Create an AMI of the existing instance
- Launch a new instance from that AMI
- Include a User Data script that completes the configuration and starts the desired apps

**Other methods**

If you wish to get more serious about software configuration and running scripts on instances, you could look at:

- **AWS CodeDeploy:** Good for deploying and updating code on existing instances
- [AWS Systems Manager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/what-is-systems-manager.html): Includes capabilities to run scripts on instances, patch software, take inventory

For more information about User Data scripts, see: [Running Commands on Your Linux Instance at Launch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html)

Comment: Thanks John. But what's the best approach for launching the instance using the AMI through a Node.js program, not using the web console. There is some complete CLI command for that (I can craft and execute this command through my program), or via AWS SDK?

Comment: [RunInstances - Amazon EC2 JavaScript API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_RunInstances.html)

Comment: RunInstances is perfect for that. I already have the AMI (Image ID) used for manual clone, I'll just pass it to the request. Very straightforward indeed. Thanks John. I would up vote the answer but I still don't have enough stack overflow reputation for that.